# How to upload image file with text data in same row on parse?

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I have written some code to upload some text to parse using html and JavaScript. 
I have uploaded successfully text data, when I try to upload image it is uploading but problem is that it uploading in different row of class. How can I upload text and image in same row of same class?

Comment: does any one has sample code to do this

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what questions you can ask and how to ask.

Comment: i have to upload image on parse using javascript . may anyone give me the link for related query thanks

Comment: That is not how SO works. Please read why and how in the [help]

Comment: Post some code for us to see what may be wrong.